# Gamecenter for Clash of Clans

Tags: itunes, ipad, ipod-touch, apple-id, clash-of-clans

I have 2 CoC accounts. One on my ipod 4th gen, the other on my ipad 2. I want to link the account from my ipod to my ipad. I signed into gc on my ipad and it started a new account. I read some posts earlier that said to make a new gc account then sign into hat one on the new device. I made a new apple id on my ipod; then made a new gc with that apple id. It doesnt seem to work though, it says "(null)". Do I need the same apple id on my ipad thats with the new gc??? Sorry if this is too complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Supercell does not use Game Center to store progress or files of your CoC account. I recommend installing a program called Ifunbox and going into your iPod and copying all the files in the CoC app and paste them into your iPad's CoC app. If you don't understand how to do what I just told you ask for further instructions and ill make a youtube video to help.

Comment: Yes, please make a video. I have already checked and I have ifunbox already installed on this mac. I don't know how to use it though. ;)

Comment: Can you still make the video, @Backspacehacker?